# Word Ribbon XML: Collapsed group only showing default image

Tags: xml, image, ms-word, ribbon

We have a Word Add-in implemented in C++ as COM Add-in. Our ribbon group is loaded using the GetCustomUI callback. When Word 2010  displays our ribbon group in a collapsed layout, only a  default icon is shown.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabReviewWord">
        <group id="MyGroup" label="My AddIn" getImage="GetGroupImage" insertAfterMso="GroupProofing" >
        .......



STDMETHODIMP CWordPlugIn::GetGroupImage(IDispatch* pRibbon, IPictureDisp** ppdispImage)
{
   return GetImage(GetGroupIcon(16), ppdispImage);
};

HRESULT CWordPlugIn::GetImage(HICON hIcon, IPictureDisp** ppdispImage)
{
   PICTDESC    pd;
   memset(&pd, 0, sizeof(pd));
   pd.cbSizeofstruct = sizeof(pd);
   pd.picType = PICTYPE_ICON;
   pd.icon.hicon = hIcon;
   if ( pd.icon.hicon == NULL )
   {
      return E_INVALIDARG;
   };

   HRESULT     hRes = OleCreatePictureIndirect(&pd, IID_IPictureDisp, FALSE, (LPVOID *) ppdispImage);
   if ( hRes != S_OK )
   {
      //write log
   };

   return hRes;
};
```

When I do not define the "getImage" callback for the group, the collapsed group shows a Microsoft default icon. When I define the "getImage" callback, my icon is not displayed, just an empty image. The same callback works perfectly for button icons. How do I define a group icon programmatically that is displayed for collapsed groups? I tried both, 16 and 32 pixel icons.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: When I return an icon that contains both, 16 and 32 (and 48 pixel) images, it works as expected.

For whatever reason, we used different icon resources (individual files containing 16 or 32 pixel icons) for the small and large ribbon buttons. Instead, one should use icons containing all sizes in one single icon file. Bonus: When the icon contains a 48 pixel image as well, the ribbon buttons are painted correctly for upscaled system fonts.

Comment: hIcon would only contain a single resolution icon, so doubt it has to do with multiple resolution icons in a single file. Most likely it has to do with color depth. What color depth did you use?

Comment: How are you doing that Wolfgang? Doesn't your callback return a System.Drawing.Bitmap? If not, what are you returning?

Comment: Sorry, I non longer have access to the source code.